# what causes epigenetic dysregulation in cancer?

Tags: cancer, epigenetics

Do mutations in regulatory gene sequences lead to changes in epigenetic alterations   in cancer, and if so which ones? I know abnormal hypermethylation of GCP islands occurs in promoters of tumour supressors, but what drives the abnormal methylation? Thanks

Comment: Your question is very broad. There are multiple factors that lead to epigenetic changes. I am not sure if the "first" signal that causes cancer progression has been identified but many histone modification proteins (HDAC, HMT etc) are dysregulated and are even being considered as targets of cancer therapy. So, to answer "what really causes the epigenetic dysregulation" an entire review article would be required.

Comment: But ultimately are epigenetic changes due to changes in gene sequence from mutational events? For example, would gene sequence change cause increase activity of DNA methyltransferase to cause increased methylation?